Can Cytoscape 3 export network.js as UTF-8?
When I set multibyte string(Japanese words) to a node label and export as Full web application, an exported 'network.js'(in 'web_session/data' directory) is encoded as 'ISO 8859-2'(detected by VSCode automatically). And when I reopen 'network.js' as UTF-8, the node label is not encoded correctly.
Can Cytoscape 3 export network.js as UTF-8?
